# Akka Actor how to handle Out of memory exception at ThreadPool

Tags: c#, concurrency, actor, akka.net

I have a basic akka actor system in a window service. It does a few jobs within the system. Once in every month, it throws 'Out of memory exception at Threadpool' then the service get stopped.  Then, I need to re-start the service manually every time it happens.

The below piece of codes show how I implemented:

```
     _actorSystem =
                        ActorSystem.Create(_ACTOR_SYSTEM_NAME);
    _imageDownloadActor = 
                    _actorSystem.ActorOf<ImageDownloadActor>("ImageDownload");
    _imageResizeActor = 
                    _actorSystem.ActorOf<ImageResizeActor>("ImageResize");

    _imageImportActor = 
                    _actorSystem.ActorOf<ImageImportActor>("ImageImport");

void Process()
{
      _imageDownloadActor.DoProcess();
    _imageResizeActor.DoProcess();
    _imageImportActor.DoProcess();

}
```

The program works perfectly - picks up the process and do the jobs correctly. But, as i said above - it shuts down at some point and i have to re-start manually.

Can anyone advise where I did wrongly in Akka actor system setup? Is there anyway i can handle the exception?

Comment: Put a try/catch round it, if it gets memory issues, restart the service?

Comment: If I do that, i will lose the actor messages. That will give me problem as well.

Comment: Beforr restart you could save the queue

Answer (score 0):

Your problem suggests, that there's a memory leak somewhere in your application. The snippet you've presented is not enough to identify it.

Quite probably somewhere during message processing, you're keeping a reference to object / not releasing the necessary resource. Memory allocated this way will start to pile up, as the referenced object will never get garbage collected.